# I am attempting to send emails with the mail function in php via localhost (XAMPP) however the email is not sending. How do I achieve it?

Tags: php, html, email

How would I send an email using the mail function on php with localhost(xampp)?
My php.ini file is:

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com  
smtp_port = 465 
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
sendmail_from = senders email
```

My sendmail.ini file is:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465 
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=email address
auth_password=password
force_sender=sender's email
```

My code is:

```
$to_email = "email address";
$subject = "Subject";
$body = "msg";
$headers = "From: email address";

if (mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "Email successfully sent to $to_email...";
} else {
    echo "Email sending failed...";
}
```

Comment: did you check your spam folder after triggering the send mail function?

Comment: First check I would check if the error log gives any clue about why it failed to send. You might need the proper SMTP settings for example. If you have no luck there try grabbing a free mailtrap.io account and testing with that just to see if its a settings issue vs. an XAMMP issue.

Comment: how do i find the error log

Comment: its not in my spam folder as well

Comment: And what's the question? Anything not working with the given code?